# Set dataframe values based on both row-dependent and column-dependent conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Situation

Consider a dataframe `df` that contains the following columns:

- One column named `amount`. All values in this column are either a whole number > 0, or NaN.
- Multiple columns named `property_1`, `property_2`, `property_3`, and so on. The values in these columns are arbitrary.

A simple example `df` would be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [2, 7., 2., 4., 3.],
    [np.nan, 8., 3., 4., 2.],
    [3, 9., 1., 5., 6.],
    [1, 8., 2., 4., 1.],
]
columns = ['amount', 'property_1', 'property_2', 'property_3', 'property_4']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

which looks as follows in console output:

```
   amount  property_1  property_2  property_3  property_4
0     2.0         7.0         2.0         4.0         3.0
1     NaN         8.0         3.0         4.0         2.0
2     3.0         9.0         1.0         5.0         6.0
3     1.0         8.0         2.0         4.0         1.0
```

### Problem

I would like to transform `df` into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   amount  property_1  property_2  property_3  property_4
0     2.0         7.0         2.0         NaN         NaN
1     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2     3.0         9.0         1.0         5.0         NaN
3     1.0         8.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Basically I'd like to set a NaN value at all locations where either the number suffix of the column name is greater than the `amount` value or the `amount` value is NaN.

I have the feeling there must be a clever way to accomplish this with some vectorized dataframe operations. Does anybody have an idea how exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct Boolean masks for your first condition using `np.subtract.outer`. The second null condition is handled via `fillna(0)` since all positive integers are greater than 0.

```
# extract integers from columns
ints = df.columns[1:].str.rsplit('_', n=1).str[-1].astype(int)

# perform elementwise comparison after replacing null amounts with 0
bool_arr = np.subtract.outer(ints, df['amount'].fillna(0)).T

# apply Boolean mask to selected columns
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mask(bool_arr > 0)

print(df)

   amount  property_1  property_2  property_3  property_4
0     2.0         7.0         2.0         NaN         NaN
1     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2     3.0         9.0         1.0         5.0         NaN
3     1.0         8.0         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: Many thanks! This code works perfectly for the example dataframe. I just noticed however that if I have one additional row in the input dataframe, then the second code line raises a `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare` error. Does this mean that the code doesn't work if the input dataframe has a different number of rows than the number of 'property' columns? If so, can the code be adapted to handle that situation?

Comment: @Xukrao, Apologies, there was a bug, now corrected :)

Comment: I now get `TypeError: ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''` from the last code line (the one with the`mask` operation). Does that make any sense?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6, NumPy 1.13.1, and don't see any errors. `np.subtract.outer`, conceptually takes the difference between all combinations of 2 1d arrays to give a 2d matrix. You then need to transpose the result via `.T`.

Comment: Interesting. I'm using python 3.7.2, numpy 1.15.4 and pandas 0.23.4. Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: I just ran on 3.7 / 1.15 / 0.23 and see the same error as you! think my edit *should* fix it now!